# CS7036 error message using a Partial.cshtml file in a Pages folder in asp.net core razor pages C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am building an application using Asp.net core Razor pages C# in Visual Studio Enterprise 2019. I want to add a calendar app to an existing application. I added a form called `CRUDPartial.cshtml` in the Calendars folder under the Pages folder.

However, an error is thrown on the first line of code and the `BeginForm` is highlighted in red:

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm(Model.ActionName, Paths.INDEX_PATH, new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="well bs-component custom-background2">
        <div class="row" style="display:none;">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10 col-md-pull-1">
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Event_id, new { @readonly = "readonly", placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Event_id), @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.IsView, new { @readonly = "readonly", placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.IsView), @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ButtonText, new { @readonly = "readonly", placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.ButtonText), @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.StartDateTime, new { id = "startDateVal", @readonly = "readonly", placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.StartDateTime), @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.EndDateTime, new { id = "endDateVal", @readonly = "readonly", placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.EndDateTime), @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The error message is:

CS7036: - There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'htmlAttributes' of 'IHtmlHelper.BeginForm(string, string, object, FormMethod, bool?, object)'

When I build the solution, the output from the build throws an error message at the point:-
Done building project "ProjectName.csproj" -- FAILED.

This is followed by some more error messages: -
CS0246 - The type or namespace name 'PrivacyModel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

and the error message occurs at these code lines:

```html
 public global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.IHtmlHelper<PrivacyModel> Html { get; private set; }
public global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewDataDictionary<PrivacyModel> ViewData => (global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewDataDictionary<PrivacyModel>)PageContext?.ViewData;
```

Any help to fix these issues will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Html helpers is very yesterday. When creating new apps, you should use tag library, then you can skip stuff like @Html.AntiForgeryToken(), it will be added automatically.

Comment: @RoarS.: do you mean The Tag helpers library which are found in the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers? I tried it but it still shows an error is thrown on the first line of code and the "BeginForm" is highlighted in red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Html.BeginForm` helper should not be used in Razor Pages. It is designed to support form submissions to MVC controllers and actions. You should use the [form tag helper](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/tag-helpers/form-tag-helper) instead.

But the reason for your error message is that the .NET Core `IHtmlHelper.BeginForm`  method [expects 6 arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.ihtmlhelper.beginform?view=aspnetcore-3.1). You have only provided 5.

Answer (score 0):

Example for MVC

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName",
                new { area = "AreaName" }, FormMethod.Post, new
                {
                    @class = "col-6"
                }))
                    {
                    }
```

And example for Core

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName",
                    new { area = "AreaName" }, FormMethod.Post,null, new
                    {
                        @class = "col-6"
                    }))
                        {
                        }
```